# Confusion between 誰でも and 誰か

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particle-か, particle-でも, interrogatives

I was practicing and tried to write the following sentence in Japanese: Anyone playing games on PS4 or Switch?

> 誰でもPS4でゲームをやっていますか。スイッチでゲームをやっていますか。

A few minutes later my sentence was corrected to

> **誰か**PS4でゲームをやっていますか。スイッチでゲームをやっていますか。

Why was using 誰でも wrong here? I thought 誰でも meant anyone and 誰か meant someone.

Unfortunately the person who corrected me, presumably a native speaker, couldn't explain it very well when asking the same question. It sounds like they were trying to say I could only use 誰でも when presented with multiple options. So now I'm just overall super confused

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be careful when translating to/from English because there is some overlap with certain words like these.

**誰でも** means "anyone" in the sense of "whoever".

> - マラソンに参加する人は誰でもTシャツをもらう　→　**Anyone who**/**Whoever** participates in the marathon will receive a T-shirt
> - [MPAAレーティング・システムで「G」とは誰でも見られる作品です](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0-162265)　→　In the MPAA rating system, a "G" (movie) is one that **anyone** can watch

**誰か** means "anyone" in the sense of "someone".

> - （暗い部屋に入ってひやひやと呼びかけて）誰かいる（の）？　→　(Entering a dark room, calling out in fear) Is **anyone**（**someone**） here?
> - 誰か助けて！　→　**Somebody** help me!
> - （落とした財布を拾いながら）誰かのものかな、これ…　→　(Picking up a dropped wallet) This must belong to **someone** (as opposed to being trash)...

So if you use these definitions, you can see your sentence is essentially the same as my first example of 誰か; "whoever" doesn't make sense because that's not what you're asking.