JLPT5 grammar question: Why 誰も and not 誰か?
I just stumpled across this question from a JLPT5 grammar test:
部屋には 誰 ...  いません

が、か、も、は

The correct answer is 誰も. however I wasn't able to explain why I cannot use 誰か in this case.
So I did some research (please correct me):

誰 means who (?)
誰も means everyone, anyone, nobody, no one (with neg. verb)
誰か means someone, somebody
誰か can be used for affirmative and interrogative sentences

部屋には誰かいますか　is there someone in the room?
部屋には誰かいます someone is in the room



so the vertict is, you can't use 誰か in negative sentence (because there is no negative from):

部屋には誰かいません: there is someone not in my room

and you have to use 誰も:

部屋には誰もいません: there is nobody in my room

and can you use 誰も in a question?

部屋には誰もいますか: is there anyone in the room?

I also read this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72528/35653

English has similar usage restrictions to Japanese in this case, for pretty much the same reason. It's not that it's grammatically wrong to say "There isn't somebody in my room," it just doesn't make sense. In both English and Japanese, the correct way to state it is "There isn't anybody in my room."

@YKa Very minor nitpick, but I wouldn’t go so far as to say that “There isn’t anybody” is “the correct way” in English, since in my dialect (American English) I’d be much more likely to say “There’s nobody in my room.” So for me, this question acts as yet another illustration that literal English-to-Japanese translations often aren’t the way to go :-P

@JoshGrosso I agree, and my use of "the" was slightly sloppy. In this case I just thought that the English translations illustrated that there's a direct parallel between language usage here. Unfortunately the edit period has passed.

誰も means everyone, anyone, nobody, no one (with neg. verb)  You answered your own question.

This isn't strictly a problem of grammar. There is no prohibition against using 誰か in a negative sentence. For example, you can say 「誰かいませんか」 to inquire whether someone is in a room.
The problem with the sentence 「部屋には誰かいません」 is that the meaning is convoluted. When you use 誰か, you are hypothesizing a single person whose identity is unknown: a somebody. Then you are saying that said somebody is not in the room. The statement says nothing about other people; there may be dozens of other people in the room or there may be zero. You are just stating that there is a single person of unknown identity that is not in the room.

ok now I understand it - seems like the difference between anyone and someone (for some reason) wasn't obvious to me but now you pointed it out it makes a lot more sense! thank you
